# Restart node server using crontab

Tags: node.js, cron, forever

I have a node.js server that I run using forever and I want to restart this server every hour using crontab.

In crontab I have written the following command to restart the server:

```
 0 * * * * forever restart --minUptime 31536000000 --spinSleepTime 2000 /home/ubuntu/gt02/gt2.js
```

When I run the same command manually on the terminal then it will restart the server successfully, but the server is not getting restarted automatically using crontab.

Below is small snippet from the cron.log file that is getting printed every hour

```
 Jun 22 17:00:01 ip-172-31-16-234 CRON[16722]: (root) CMD (forever restart --minUptime 31536000000 --spinSleepTime 2000 /home/ubuntu/gt02/gt2.js)
 Jun 22 17:00:01 ip-172-31-16-234 CRON[16721]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here and how to properly restart the server using contab

Comment: Have you tried providing a full path to forever? try `which forever`

Comment: Is this fine ?
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/forever restart --minUptime 31536000000 --spinSleepTime 2000 /home/ubuntu/gt02/gt2.js

Comment: Try it from the command line; if it works, it should work from crontab.

Comment: when i  run `sudo crontab -e` and `crontab -e` then different files open and by putting the same code in `crontab -e` it is working but it was not working when I was putting this in `sudo crontab -e` . Can you tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: A user's crontab is different than sudo's crontab. sudo's crontab doesn't have access to the environment that your user has. To better test your stuff, create a `.sh` file and write your code in it and run in in crontab. Good luck.